# Using arrays, loops, and hashes- don't know how to finish/expand this code

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, hash

I'm writing a program to practice arrays, etc in Ruby and I'm unsure what to do next. I really don't know how to put everything together. Advice would be helpful. Thanks.

I am selling shirts ($2) and shoes ($6) with an arbitrary number of friends. I want to create a program that will take the following input.

- Name of person selling
- Number of shirts they sold
- Number of shirts they didn't sell
- Number of shoes they sold
- Number of shoes they didn't sell

and it will output:

- How much money each person received
- Who received the most money
- Total amount of money from shirts
- Total amount of money from shoes
- Net money raised

Here's what I have so far:

https://gist.github.com/greenbottle88/e17ec8406aade496e38a9140d39c3052

This is all I know how to do and I'm not really sure where to go from here. Right now I get an error of "undefined local variable or method `seller' for main:Object". But besides that error, I just don't know what to do next and I'm sure what I have attempted needs some fixing.

Comment: Please, add the code to your question. Also, please make sure you edit your code to a [mcve]. I highly doubt it requires 52 lines to demonstrate the problem. Also, please add the *precise* error message you are getting to your question. In particular, it would be helpful to know *where* that error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be a working version of the code you linked. See the comments inside.
Then you must work on arrays to get the information you want.

```
puts "Welcome to your Sale Tracker! Answer some questions below to learn more about your business. Press ENTER to get started."

# Wait for user to press ENTER
pause = STDIN.gets

# Creating arrays
sellers_array = []
shirt_profit_array = []
shoe_profit_array = []
total_profit_array = []
net_profit_array = []

# Using a loop to keep prompting the user for information until they have input all their sellers

loop do

  puts "Name of seller:"
  seller = gets.chomp!

  puts "How many shirts did #{seller} sell?"
  shirts_sold = gets.chomp!.to_i # you must convert the string input to integer

  puts "How many of #{seller}'s shirts remained unsold?"
  shirts_unsold = gets.chomp!.to_i # you must convert the string input to integer

  puts "How many shoes did #{seller} sell?"
  shoes_sold = gets.chomp!.to_i # you must convert the string input to integer

  puts "How many of #{seller}'s  shoes remained unsold?"
  shoes_unsold = gets.chomp!.to_i # you must convert the string input to integer

  puts "Do you have another seller you would like to add? If yes, press ENTER. If no, type 'n'"

  sellers_array << seller

  shirt_profit = shirts_sold * 2 # assignment works this way, == is a comparison
  shirt_profit_array << shirt_profit

  shoe_profit = shoes_sold * 6 # assignment works this way, == is a comparison
  shoe_profit_array << shoe_profit

  total_profit = shirt_profit + shoe_profit # assignment works this way, == is a comparison
  total_profit_array << total_profit

  net_profit = (shirt_profit - (shirts_unsold * 2)) + (shoe_profit - (shoes_unsold * 6)) # assignment works this way, == is a comparison
  net_profit_array << net_profit

  command = STDIN.gets
  break if command.chomp! == "n"

end # you must do calculation and fill arrays inside the loop and each time the loop runs

puts "shirt_profit_array " + shirt_profit_array.to_s
puts "shoe_profit_array" + shoe_profit_array.to_s
puts "total_profit_array" + total_profit_array.to_s
puts "net_profit_array" + net_profit_array.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

It says the error is at line 40. That should give you an indication of where to look to find that error. If we go to line 40 we see that you call

```
seller << sellers_array
```

However, seller is not defined in our current [scope](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/ruby_tutorial/Ruby_Expressions_Variable_Scope_and_Loops.html). seller is defined within the loop but not outside of the loop, so after the loop finishes, we do not have access to that seller variable. To fix this, simply define seller globally (before the loop) and then you will be able to access that variable.

You have other issues in your code- but StackOverflow isn't really the place for people to fix all the issues in your code, or to do your homework for you. I hope my explanation helps you with your initial error. For the next errors you get in your project:

- Look at the line number the error points to
- Google the Error
- Attempt to Resolve the Error
- Create a new question on StackOverflow only if you have exhausted all other online resources and are still stuck.

I also recommend reading about [debugging](http://www.rubyguides.com/2015/07/ruby-debugging/) in Ruby. Debugging is a skill not emphasized as much as it should be in school, but it is a highly valuable skill you should attempt to master.